# Я, конечно, отъезжаю, но(,) что никакого ответа не было, страши́т меня

Tags: орфография

Нужна запятая?

> Я, конечно, отъезжаю, но(,) что никакого ответа не было, страши́т меня.

Answer (score 1):

Я, конечно, уеду, но то, что никакого ответа не получено, будет больно осознавать.

Comment: Высокий стиль...)